# Angular Unit testing with Input decorator throw error

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-unit-test

here is my component which i run testing:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'shell-bread-crumbs',
    templateUrl: './shell-bread-crumbs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shell-bread-crumbs.component.scss']
})
export class ShellBreadCrumbsComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() breadCrumb;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

here is my spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ShellBreadCrumbsComponent } from './shell-bread-crumbs.component';

describe('ShellBreadCrumbsComponent', () => {

  let component: ShellBreadCrumbsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShellBreadCrumbsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ShellBreadCrumbsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShellBreadCrumbsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.breadCrumb = ""; //i given empty declaration,
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But still getting an error as :

```
Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'breadCrumb' since it isn't a known property of 'bread-crumbs'.
    1. If 'bread-crumbs' is an Angular component and it has 'breadCrumb' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'bread-crumbs' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<bread-crumbs [ERROR ->][breadCrumb]="breadCrumb"></bread-crumbs>")
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use `bread-crumbs` within `shell-bread-crumbs.component.html`

There are two things you can do

1. Import `BreadCrumbsModule` or declare `BreadCrumbsComponent` within `TestBed`

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ 
          ShellBreadCrumbsComponent,
          BreadCrumbsComponent // if you own this component
      ],
      imports: [BreadCrumbsModule] // if you have module
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

This way, Angular will recognize `bread-crumbs`. However, this may create other problems. `BreadCrumbsComponent` may have other dependencies and use other components that you need to declare or define. Also, you may not care about `BreadCrumbsComponent` for this test which brings us to second thing you can do

2. Use `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` so that angular will skip over elements it does not recognize. You can do it as follows

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ShellBreadCrumbsComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: I am finding challenges in Input, Output and mocking, I am using ngrx/store and effects. all need to be tested. can you share me good tutorial to lean all?